# I am trying to create a function that increases an employees salary if they are on the promotion list

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out how I can edit a value in a dictionary by testing for equality in a dictionaries keys against an array's value

So I've figured it out almost and I'm stuck trying to replace the value in the dictionary with a value that gets returned from a function.

```
for (key, value) in employeeSal {

    for name in promotionList {

        if key == name {

            promotion(salary: value)

            print(key, promotion(salary: value))
            employeeSal[key: value]

        }   
    }
}
```

The, ***print(key, promotion(salary: value)***, shows me exactly what I want it to. I tried to assign the new value to the key with, ***employeeSal[key: value]***, but it is not working and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the result of `promotion` to a variable. The. Use that to update the dictionary.

```
let newSalary = promotion(salary: value)
employeeSal[key] = newSalary
```

There’s a much more efficient solution:

```
for name in promotionList {
    if let value = employeeSal[name] {
        let newSalary = promotion(salary: value)
        employeeSal[name] = newSalary
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I ended up being able to use:                                                   
````                                                                     
employeeSal.updateValue(newSalary, forKey: key) .                                               ````

Comment: Or just use the code I posted. No need for `updateValue`.

Comment: Okay. I'll give it a try. Thank you.